# Double sum with double index variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I probably have trivial question for this forum but I just cannot wrap my head around it. I need to calculate sum using the the following formula:

$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n E_i E_j \rho_{ij}}$

I am also given variables $E_i = 30$,  $E_j = 40$ and $\rho_{ij} = 0.4$.

I know that $\sqrt{30^2 + 40^2 + 2 \times 0.4 \times 30 \times 40} = 58.8$ is the solution but could you explain to me the procedure itself?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding something.  If all of the variables are already given as constants, wouldn't the value inside the sum always be $30\times 40\times 0.4=180$?

Comment: The problem is it is not, the example is taken directly from the Hull's "Financial Risk Management" book chapter 26 (Example 26.3), I just disregarded the square root.

Comment: Perhaps you don't know what the summation notation means. http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/summation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the given solution doesn't make any sense unless you specify a value of $n$. It appears that $n = 2$ here, so your sum is actually
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^2E_iE_j\rho_{ij} &= \sum_{i=1}^2(E_iE_1\rho_{i1}+E_iE_2\rho_{i2})\\
&= \color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^2E_iE_1\rho_{i1}}+\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^2E_iE_2\rho_{i2}} \\
&= \color{red}{E_1E_1\rho_{11} + E_2E_1\rho_{21}} + \color{blue}{E_1E_2\rho_{12} + E_2E_2\rho_{22}}.
\end{align*}
Now use your knowledge of the variables $E_1,E_2$, and $\rho_{ij}$ to finish.